# Odoo auto create records on module install

Tags: odoo, record, product, autofill

I'd like to make some products (data records) automatically when I install my module. Any ideas?

Is this possible from the views.xml?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For creating  the demo data for the specific model try this link

- Demo data for [product category](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9.0/addons/product/product_data.xml).
- Demo data for [payment_authorize](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9.0/addons/payment_authorize/data/authorize.xml).

Ensure these two thing:

1. Place `noupdate="1"` with the data tag.
2. Make it entry in openerp.py Like:

   ```
    'data': [       
       'data/my_demo_data.xml',       
    ],
   ```

Comment: Any idea how I can link a search function to this, I need to place the ID of another model in a record field. This ID I need to search for in the other table.

Comment: hi @jesse , you can use reference :  ref="module_name.demo_data_id", open the product_category link

Comment: thanks it works! The only thing I'm working on right now is on how to reference to a Many2Many tabel. I tried this         <record id="werkcenter_rule_group_rel_plakkerij" model="rule.group.rel">
            <field name="group_id" ref="group_plakkerij"/>
            <field name="rule_group_id" ref="rule_werkcenter_plakkerij"/>
        </record>
But got the error that rule.group.rel is no model

Comment: you want to create a record in many2many using demo data?? am   i  right